# Multiple bands per group using plot_model

Tags: r

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
id  = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 62, 63, 64, 65, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
       19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
       40, 62, 63, 64, 65, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
       29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 62, 63, 64, 65), 
collection_point = c(rep(c("Baseline", "Immediate", "3M"), each=28)), 
intervention = c(rep(c("B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", 
              "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A"), each = 4)), 
scale_A = c(6.5, 7.0, 6.25, 6.0, NA, 7.5, 7.5, 
        8.0, 7.5, 6.75, 7.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.5, 
        5.75, 6.75, 7.75, 7.5, 7.75, 7.25, 7.75, 
        7.25, 7.25, 5.75, 6.75, NA, 6.75, 7.5, 
        6.75, 7.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
        7.75, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.5, 6.5, 6.25, 
        6.25, 7.25, 7.5, 6.75, 7.25, 7.25, 7.5, 
        7.25, 7.5, 7.25, NA, 7.0, 7.5, 7.5, 
        6.75, 7.25, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
        7.75, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 6.5, 5.75, 
        6.25, 6.75, 7.5, 7.25, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 
        7.75, 7.75, 7.5, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

where,

`id` = participant

`collection_point` = times data was collected from participant (repeated measure)

`intervention` = group each participant was randomized to (fixed effect)

`scale_A` = questionnaire score that each participant completed at each data collection point (outcome)

Participants were randomized to one of three interventions and completed the same scales (scales A-C) at three different time points to determine any improvements over time.

I have used the code

```
    mixed.lmer.A1<-lmer(scale_A~intervention*collection_point+(collection_point|id), control =
 lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"), data = df)
```

I can use `plot_model(mixed.lmer.A1)` and use the function `terms` to select only the interaction effects (ex: `terms = c("interventionB:collection_point3M")` to create a forest plot. However, I think it would look much neater to only have the interventions on the y axis and have multiple bands that represent each collection_point. Desired output like this:

[image: example.png]

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: @jared_mamrot I had to use the override check to create an example similar to a subset of my data. I know that the warning message does pop up but I was just trying to create an example to show what the forest plot would look like! Unfortunately, I wasn't sure how else to do it. I can still create a forest plot similar to my actual dataset with that code though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(sjPlot)
#> Install package "strengejacke" from GitHub (`devtools::install_github("strengejacke/strengejacke")`) to load all sj-packages at once!

df <- data.frame(
  id  = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
          34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 62, 63, 64, 65, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
          19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
          40, 62, 63, 64, 65, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
          29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 62, 63, 64, 65), 
  collection_point = c(rep(c("Baseline", "Immediate", "3M"), each=28)), 
  intervention = c(rep(c("B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", 
                         "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A"), each = 4)), 
  scale_A = c(6.5, 7.0, 6.25, 6.0, NA, 7.5, 7.5, 
              8.0, 7.5, 6.75, 7.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.5, 
              5.75, 6.75, 7.75, 7.5, 7.75, 7.25, 7.75, 
              7.25, 7.25, 5.75, 6.75, NA, 6.75, 7.5, 
              6.75, 7.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
              7.75, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.5, 6.5, 6.25, 
              6.25, 7.25, 7.5, 6.75, 7.25, 7.25, 7.5, 
              7.25, 7.5, 7.25, NA, 7.0, 7.5, 7.5, 
              6.75, 7.25, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
              7.75, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 6.5, 5.75, 
              6.25, 6.75, 7.5, 7.25, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 
              7.75, 7.75, 7.5, NA, NA, NA, NA))

mixed.lmer.A1 <- lmer(scale_A~intervention*collection_point+(collection_point|id), control =
                      lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"), data = df)
#> Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :
#> unable to evaluate scaled gradient
#> Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :
#> Model failed to converge: degenerate Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

plot_model(mixed.lmer.A1, type = "int") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I want! But when I do `type = "int"` I get the following error message: Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “est”, “re”, “eff”, “emm”, “pred”, “int”, “std”, “std2”, “slope”, “resid”, “diag”. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you're using? It might be a typo

Comment: `plot_model(mixed.lmer.A1, type = "int") + coord_flip()`

Comment: That runs without issue for me... Perhaps try restarting your R session?

Comment: It worked, thank you! Is there a way I could change the x axis to show the estimates instead of the score if I wanted?

Comment: Glad it worked! I'm not sure about displaying the estimates instead of the score; if you create a new question perhaps someone will know